# sync axios request in node.js

Tags: node.js, axios

i want to make sync axios request in node JS but i failed to understand async await or promiseall, what i want is:

req(A) => req(B) => req(C) => req(A - new cookie from req C ) => req(B) => ....

so far i only got to this step:

```
var cookie=init
for (let index = start; index < end; index++) {
    await axios.get('URL1', {
    headers: {
        //cookie
    }
    })
    .then((response) => {
        //do calculation with response
            await axios.get('URL' + calculatedresponse, {
            headers: {
               //cookie
            }
            })
            .then((response2) => {
                //do calculation with response2
                await axios.get('URL3', {
                    headers: {
                        //cookie
                    }
                    })
                    .then((response3) => {
                        get new cookie here
                        cookie= newcookie
                    });
            });
    });
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using recursion,

```
const processItems = (x,y,cookie) => {
  if( x < y ) {
    axios.get('URL1', {
    headers: {
        //cookie
    }
    })
    .then((response) => {
        //do calculation with response
            axios.get('URL' + calculatedresponse, {
            headers: {
               //cookie
            }
            })
            .then((response2) => {
                //do calculation with response2
                axios.get('URL3', {
                    headers: {
                        //cookie
                    }
                    })
                    .then((response3) => {
                        get new cookie here
                        cookie= newcookie
                        processItems(x+1,y,cookie)
                    });
            });
    });
  }
}
```